# Python script to access a host with ssh and run commands in the host

Tags: python, shell, ssh

I am trying to write a python script that will allow me to ssh into a host, run a curl command, and then parse the output of the command.

I am trying something like

```
os.system('ssh HOST')
os.system('curl ...')
```

However, the curl command does not execute on the server. I get into the server but have no connection to it from the python script anymore. I need to be able to execute the curl command and access the output so I can parse it. Any ideas how I can accomplish this? Thanks.

Comment: Why not use pycurl?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To access the output of any command that you run , use the `subprocess` module. It gives a lot of control over the os commands that you run. Here is a code snippet.

```
import subprocess
process_object = subprocess.Popen(['cat','myfile.txt'],stdout=subprocess.PIPE , stderr = subprocess.STDOUT) ;
output = process_object.stdout.read()
```

Likewise your use `['ssh','HOST','argument2','argument3']` for your implementation. I'm not sure if this fixes your curl not executing problem. But it helps to get the output .

Comment: how would I take in a part of the curl argument as an input from the user? for example argument2 needs to be something like 'curl -s "input"' where the user can specify the input.

Answer (score 0):

Supply the call to `curl(1)` in your `ssh(1)` command like `ssh user@host curl somehost/somefile -o -`.  Use the python subprocess module to get the result.